# Exporting State Level Data from uszipcode in Python

Tags: python, database, export-to-csv, zipcode

I am very new to python and am having trouble getting data from the package uszipcode. I'd like to be able to have a csv or excel file of all of the zip codes in Oregon and all of the associated data with each zip code (i.e. population, housing units, etc).

What I have tried so far is:

```
from uszipcode import SearchEngine
search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode = False)

zipcode = search.by_state("Oregon", zipcode_type=None)
```

I am unsure how to proceed from here. How do I get all of the Oregon zipcode data into an excel or csv format from here.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
search.by_state('OR', returns=1000)
```

---

Or use [uszipcode](https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/02-Migrate-to-0.2.x/index.html)'s database file directly.

as the document mention:

> Database file doesn’t come with the installation. The **download will be automatically started if you don’t have it. The database file stored at `${HOME}/.uszipcode`.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

# replace ${HOME} with your home direction
with sqlite3.connect("${HOME}/.uszipcode/simple_db.sqlite") as con:
    df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from simple_zipcode", con)

print(df.head())

# convert the `CompressedJSONType` to str
# from https://github.com/MacHu-GWU/uszipcode-project/blob/master/uszipcode/pkg/compressed_json_type.py

import zlib
for col in ['common_city_list', 'area_code_list']:
    df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: json.loads(zlib.decompress(x).decode("utf-8")))

# query state
df.query('state=="OR"')
```